# Error: No router instance found. You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app

Tags: next.js

I just started my app from using creat next app, or the app was working last night but today it doesn't work anymore when I run npm run dev for nextjs app.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: No router instance found.
You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs mostly on Windows. Make sure the path in your terminal matches in casing, then do

```
npm run dev
```

If that still doesn't work and the path shows that everything matches, do cd, and then drag the nextJS project folder onto the shell. Then run npm run dev again.

```
cd c:\Users\Darren\Desktop\Porject\Frontend\NextjsApp
```

This error occurs especially when you open up vscode and the cached pwd path for some reason doesn't work. So cd'ing into it fixes it.

If that doesn't work, then you should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.